# How to get logged in after signup in spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

In spring security, log in is done through the specified login page in the securityconfig class. Following is the code..

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/")
}
```

But I also want my users to get logged in right after they sign up. I tried something like:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.formLogin().loginPage("/login", "/signup").defaultSuccessUrl("/")
}
```

But this does not work. How do I do this in spring security?

Answer (score 0):

Auto login is not related with Spring Security Configuration file....
it's depend on your developing programming logic ...

after complete successful signup process you can call a login method,    it will be give valid login session of that user. you can try this code ...

```
@Override
public void autoLogin(String username, String password) {
    UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, userDetails.getAuthorities());

    authenticationManager.authenticate(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);

    if (usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.isAuthenticated()) {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
        logger.debug(String.format("Auto login %s successfully!", username));
    }
}
```

for more details [link1](https://hellokoding.com/registration-and-login-example-with-spring-security-spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-hsql-jsp/) [link2](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-auto-login-user-after-registration) [link3](https://coderanch.com/t/627731/frameworks/Autologin-site-registering-spring-security)